# Computing the number of working hours in a week taking into account bank holidays in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a planning as shown below:

[image]

I also have a list of bank holidays for the coming year.

[image]

What I want is to have in row 5 the number of working hours (40 hours - 8* the number of bank holidays in the current week).

How can I do this?

Comment: Use the `NETWORKDAYS` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since week definitions can vary from company to company (when a week starts, what the first week of the year is) I'd suggest adding a row elsewhere for week start and week end.

Then enter the function `=NETWORKDAYS([Your week start date], [Your week end date], $A$29:$A:$40 where your holidays are)*8`